# easiest way for firestore document to be "invalid" with timestamp

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I currently have a collection with documents containing 2 fields:

```
expired: timestamp
details: String
```

I am thinking of created a third (boolean) field which indicates whether this document is still valid (based on the timestamp). This boolean will become `false` if the current date is past the expired timestamp.

```
valid: true
```

I am wondering what's the best way to work around this. It seems the first way to comes into mind is to run a script everyday to check if it has expired, but is there a better way  for this?

PS: I'm doing this because I would only want to retrieve valid documents and ignore (not delete) invalid ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore doesn't have any way of automatically modifying document fields based on changing conditions (such as time).  You could:

1. Do what you suggest, and periodically scan for and change documents
2. Require the client to do a range query on the timestamp field using a timestamp it provides (the query would be "where expired > currentTime")
3. Schedule a function to run in the future at the expiration time, setting the "valid" boolean to false.

If you do the first one, your documents will become expired after some delay, which could be as long as the period of time between scans.

If you do the second one, you are trusting the client to provide an accurate timestamp to perform the filter.

If you do the third one, you will need a scheduling mechanism, such as Cloud Tasks, and it will be very much non-trivial to implement.  Read my article about that [here](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a).

Comment: may i just ask, it seems that 1. will involve lots of reads (if i have 10,000 documents in my collection, i'll be having 10,000 reads every day, right?). Are there any differences in the "reads" for the 3 options above?

Comment: If you have more questions, please post those separately.  I think you should be able to figure out the cost of each solution if you investigate them in context of the problem you're trying to solve, along with the actual data you're working with (which I can't see).

Comment: @Gabriel I'm looking at the same problem. You might not have to read all the docs if you set a running time window. Like check all docs that expire from today, then every other day just check the prev day. Or move expired docs to a diff collection maybe? From what I've learned checking at regular intervals might be best